# Java: Calling an instanced getter from another class return null

Tags: java, getter

I'm new into Java and want to improve my OOP skills.
Therefore I try to write all my "first programmes" object-oriented.

Anyway... I started a small primitives test programme:

```
public class Primitives {

byte b;

private void setByte (byte b)
{
    this.b = b;
}
public byte getByte() 
{
    return b;
}


short s;

private void setShort (short s)
{
    this.s = s;
}
public short getShort() 
{
    return s;
}


int i;

private void setInteger (int i)
{
    this.i = i;
}
public int getInteger() 
{
    return i;
}


long l;

private void setLong (long l)
{
    this.l = l;
}
public long getLong() 
{
    return l;
}


float f;

private void setFloat (float f)
{
    this.f = f;
}
public float getfloat() 
{
    return f;
}



double d;

private void setDouble (double d)
{
    this.d = d;
}
public double getDouble()
{
    return d;
}


boolean bool;

private void setBoolean (boolean bool)
{
    this.bool = bool;
}
public boolean getBoolean() 
{
    return bool;
}


char c;

private void setChar (char c)
{
    this.c = c;
}
public char getChar() 
{
    return c;
}


String str;

private void setString (String str)
{
    this.str = str;
}
public String getString()
{
    return str;
}


public static void main(String[] args) {

    Primitives prim = new Primitives();
    prim.setBoolean(true);
    //prim.setByte(42);
    //prim.setChar("ft");
    prim.setDouble(42.42);
    //prim.setFloat(42);
    prim.setInteger(42);
    prim.setLong(424242);
    //prim.setShort(0);
    prim.setString("fourtytwo");

    //System.out.println(integer.getInteger());
}
```

}

Afterward, I'm trying to call my getters in another class "Main":

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Primitives object = new Primitives();

    int objectInt = object.getInteger();
    String objectString = object.getString();

    System.out.println(objectInt);
    System.out.println(objectString);
}
```

}

My output is

```
0
null
```

How does this come?
I mean, I instanced (getInt for example) before, why I received 0?

I know there must 1000 answers here but I couldn't find any proper one.

Another question:
Why do I get "The method setByte(byte) in the type Primitives is not applicable for the arguments (int)" in my Setter? (that's why I comment some of the types out)

Comment: What other value do you expect to get besides `0` and `null`? It's not like you have called any setter method in your `main()` method of your `Main` class.

Comment: sry, im a beginner... i wrote down my getter and setter in my primitive class and set my values in the main. In the Class Main i wanted to call my primitives which i set up before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is : You are having two `main` classes and looks like you are running the one in the `Main` class which doesn`t initiate your variable.

The other `main` method inside your `Primitives` class never get executed, so  you have not initiated your variables actually!

**Each application should have one `main` class, and only one**

Comment: @milz_miliz So why did you make them private when you are going to call them in another class?!

Comment: I read that setters should be private. I want to set it up in Primitives and call it from (almost) anywhere else

Comment: @milz_miliz Not necessarily! I am not a big fan of setters and getters and try to avoid them mostly. But sometimes you need them, and when you do, they like to be public. This is a problem that could only be solved with changing alot of thing. for instance,the design of you Objects hierarchy. I suggest to forget the best practice at this moment and just read tutorials and write code, then try to refactor your old codes with new patterns.

Answer (score 2):

You should call the setter methods and set the value before you get them.

Comment: I tried to put my Block
Primitives prim = new Primitives();
prim.setInteger(42);

before my main in the class Primitives...

Couldnt handle it (Eclispe worte something about a missing @)